# Array to Collection: Optimized code

Tags: java, arrays, collections

Is there a better way of achieving this?

```
public static List<String> toList(String[] array) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList(array.length);

    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        list.add(array[i]);

    return list;
}
```

NOTE: **Arrays.asList(a) Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.). I don't want that behavior.** I assume that MY function above bypasses that (or am I wrong?)

So, here we have the alternative method:

```
public static List<String> toList(String[] array) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList(array.length);

    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));

    return list;
}
```

Just looking at it, **I don't believe it's FASTER than the first method**.

Comment: What do you mean in the `NOTE` section?

Comment: It means exactly what i say: i don't want any changes made to the Collection (list) to write through to the original array...

Comment: You don't *believe* it's faster than the first method? Based on what? You should really *measure* its actual performance and make decisions based on those findings. As well, if you are that concerned about performance, you should consider profiling your entire application to find out where the *real* performance bottlenecks are. Optimizing this particular code may be a waste of time if this code was never the bottleneck to begin with.

Comment: That's why i said "i don't believe". I'm not "stating". I based my comment on the two operations that need to be made (asList & addAll). As for the bottlenecks, i try to optimize the methods that will perform most operations, and this is one of them.

Comment: Fair enough. Usually the words "I believe" start raising alarm bells in my head. :)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

What do you mean by better way:

more readable:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

less memory consumption, and maybe faster (but definitely not thread safe):

```
public static List<String> toList(String[] array) {
    if (array==null) {
       return new ArrayList(0);
    } else {
       int size = array.length;
       List<String> list = new ArrayList(size);
       for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          list.add(array[i]);
       }
       return list;
    }
}
```

Btw: here is a bug in your first example:

`array.length` will raise a null pointer exception if array is null, so the check `if (array!=null)` must be done first.

Comment: Yes. I have initialized the List size after i wrote the funcion... you are right about the possible null pointer. i Will remove it from the example to avoid confusion. Anyway, by BETTER i mean FASTER.

Comment: So, the answer to your question is: the explicite for-loop is faster.

Comment: You can use [Collections.EMPTY_LIST](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#EMPTY_LIST) instead of new ArrayList(0).

Comment: @Emil Collections.EMPTY_LIST is a good idea in general, but not in this case, because there was the requirement that the result must not have a fixed size.

Comment: @Ralph your second example, as it's not accessing any state inside the method, why it's not thread-safe? Am i missing something?

Comment: @Abhishek Singh: the "problem" is the array itself, (java pass array parameters by reference). So someone could modify the array while it is copied to the list, (BTW: I am not claim that the the other variant is thread save.)

Comment: Okay, got it. A good thing to remember while writing concurrent code...thanks!

Answer (score 36):

```
Arrays.asList(array);
```

Example:

```
 List<String> stooges = Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly");
```

See [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) class documentation.

Comment: the result list is an immutable collecion, any remove or add at it will thrown an exception....

Answer (score 18):

```
Arrays.asList(array)
```

`Arrays` uses `new ArrayList(array)`. But this is not the `java.util.ArrayList`. It's very similar though. Note that this constructor takes the array and places it as the backing array of the list. So it is `O(1)`.

In case you already have the list created, `Collections.addAll(list, array)`, but that's less efficient.

**Update:** Thus your `Collections.addAll(list, array)` becomes a good option. A wrapper of it is guava's `Lists.newArrayList(array)`.

Answer (score 14):

Another way to do it:

```
Collections.addAll(collectionInstance,array);
```

Comment: The same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/4255077/4353862 that was published 2 years before!

Answer (score 9):

What about :

```
List myList = new ArrayList(); 
String[] myStringArray = new String[] {"Java", "is", "Cool"}; 

Collections.addAll(myList, myStringArray);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Comment: I believe this is the correct one! But is this method more "efficient"? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

> public ArrayList(Collection c)
>
> Constructs a list containing the
>   elements of the specified collection,
>   in the order they are returned by the
>   collection's iterator. The ArrayList
>   instance has an initial capacity of
>   110% the size of the specified
>   collection.

Taken from [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the reference of  `java.util.Collections.addAll(Collection<? super String> c, String... elements)` its implementation is similar to your first method, it says

> Adds all of the specified elements to the specified collection. Elements to be added may be specified individually or as an array. The behavior of this convenience method is identical to that of c.addAll(Arrays.asList(elements)), but this method is likely to run significantly faster under most implementations.

Its implementation in jdk is (jdk7)

```
public static <T> boolean addAll(Collection<? super T> c, T... elements) {
    boolean result = false;
    for (T element : elements)
        result |= c.add(element);
    return result;
}
```

So among your samples the better approach must be `Collections.addAll(list, array);`

Since Java 8, we can use `Stream` api which may perform better

Eg:-

```
String[] array = {"item1", "item2", "item3"};

Stream<String> stream = Stream.of(array);

//if the array is extremely large 
stream = stream.parallel();

final List<String> list = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If the array is very large we can do it as a batch operation in parallel using parallel stream (`stream = stream.parallel()`) that will utilize all CPUs to finish the task quickly. If the array length is very small parallel stream will take more time than sequential stream.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked `Arrays.asList()`; see [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. You can use the Arrays class from the java.util.* package. Then it's actually just one line of code.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Comment: NOT the same result... public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)
Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `List.of(array)` to get an immutable list.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/core/creating-immutable-lists-sets-and-maps.html#GUID-202D195E-6E18-41F6-90C0-7423B2C9B381

edit 2021-05-01 @Rup:
To get a mutable list you could use

```
var list = new ArrayList<String>(List.of(array));
```

edit 2021-05-04:
It might be faster to use

```
var list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Comment: That's the modern Java 9+ way of doing this, yes, but I think the original question wanted a mutable list - just not one that would also change the set of items in the array.